# Rotating an image in Photoshop causes transparent pixels on image border, how to stop this?

Tags: photoshop

I start with a seamless grass texture h133 w133 px, I then rotate it by 45 degrees and divide the height by 2 so i'm left with an isometric diamond shape. The background is #FF00FF that i key out when rendering my tiles.

As you can see, the diamond edges are transparent like after this process see the pic:

[closeup pic of the transparent diamond edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyw7r.png)

How to stop the transparent pixels and make them solid, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Photoshop is automatically changing the edges when you do any transformation on any object.

Try going to Menu > Edit > Preferences > General
and select 'Image Interpolation' and under that choose "Nearest Neighbor (Preserve Hard Edges)". This will make sure that the pixels stay sharp like those 8-bit artworks.